# Proving that $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\bar{z}}{z}$ does not exist

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that $$\lim_{z \to 0} \dfrac{\bar{z}}{z}\;\text{ does not exist.}$$

Not sure how to prove this. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: I feel like I've seen this before, but I'm not finding it....

Comment: Showing that a limit does not exist is easy. If you can find ways to compute the limit and get different answers, then you are done.

Comment: @Cameron I agree, same here, recently! exact same question...but where?

Answer (score 15):

Consider $z = r e^{i \theta}$, then

$$
\frac{\overline{z}}{z} = e^{-2 i \theta}
$$

and this depends on the direction $\theta$.

Answer (score 10):

Just look at the result you get when you let $z = x+0i$, and let $x$ tend to 0.

Then do the same with $z = 0 + iy$ and let $y$ tend to zero.

For the limit you want, the answers to the above two would have to be the same, but as you find ...